# show custom posts types in archives

Tags: custom-post-types

I have custom post types using the default categories

```
'taxonomies' => array('category')
```

how do I get the custom post types to appear when I click on the category link?
Do I need to edit archive.php to pull them in?

or if I have a category template? Is it a get_template request?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in your category archive template file.

```
if (is_category()) {
    global $query_string;
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if ( !$post_type ) { // if no post type is already defined
        parse_str( $query_string, $args );
        $args['post_type'] = array( 'post', 'you-custom-post-type-here' );
        query_posts( $args );
    }
}
```

You can also use the above code in any action that gets run just before the main loop.

Comment: oh ok, this seems to work as well (in functions.php) - any idea which is the best way to do it? 


`function my_get_posts( $query ) {

 if ( is_home() || is_category() || is_archive() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] )
  $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'quotes' ) );

 return $query;
}`

Comment: I can't seem to get your code to work - do  I just change the "you-custom-post-type-here" bit

Comment: Your method is more appropriate if you don't want to modify the template file, but if you are good with modifying the template file then you can use mine. But your code also adds the custom post to all other type of archives include home page and daily monthly archives.

Comment: @david arthur If this answer is correct, you should mark it as "accepted".